# WCF Service with Domain Validation

Tags: wpf, wcf, dns, windows-authentication, wcf-security

I am working on a `Messaging Application` built using `WPF` and `WCF-RESTful` site.

This application is used inside intranet as well as internet. The application prompts for authentication (custom login screen in the messaging application) when it accessed through internet (outside the domain).

We have written authentication logic in the `WCF service` like below:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
{
    if (!pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The Website's application pool is set to use `NetworkService`. The website's authentication is "Anonymous" as the Intranet User's do not require to authenticate.

I do not get any error or exception. Instead, it always returns "false" for any username even though the credential are correct.

Can you please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here http://travisspencer.com/blog/2009/07/creating-users-that-work-with.html plus if userName is in format domain\userName try to parse it from the domain name and send only the user part as argument to ValidateCredentials

Comment: Thank you. I solved it using different solution which is nothing to do with domain.